# jQuery delegated click event not firing

Tags: jquery, lightbox, delegation

For the purpose of development i'm playing around and making my own lightbox effect. I've got it to load up the overlay div with the content div in the middle and have used the standard cross icon in the top right to allow the user to close.

The problem is, when I click the cross, nothing happens. I had:

```
$('.cross').click(function() { 
    $('.popup-overlay').remove();
});
```

After a little googling around, it looks like it could be due to the fact that the content is dynamically loaded and thus I need to optimise javascript delegation. I tried using:

```
$('.popup-overlay').on('click', '.cross', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

and:

```
$('a[rel="popup"]').on('click', '.popup-overlay', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

but it isn't firing. This is the html that is dynamically loaded in.

```
<div class="popup-overlay">
    <div class="half-height">
        <div class="popup-box"> 
            <img src="assets/img/cross.png" alt="close" class="cross">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so.....

**Can someone tell me how to make it so that when I click .cross, the .popup-overlay html is removed from the body?**

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It should be `$('.popup-overlay').remove();` to start with. Notice the dot.

Comment: Will `$(document).on('click', '.cross', function() {
    alert('click');
});` pop up the alert?

Comment: sorry thats a typo on here. but is there in code, fixed

Comment: is the popup itself being reloaded? you should delegate that one too :)

Comment: @karl-andre-gagnon Thanks, that worked. Want to post it as an answer so I can award you the point?

Comment: @MarkP [Anthony Grist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21579205/2324107) already posted a good answer, just upvote him.

Comment: You were first so I offered u the points.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of delegated events is they're bound an an element that is **not** dynamically added. Your entire popup is dynamically added to the DOM so you can't bind any events to it (delegated or otherwise) - it never exists when the code executes.

Bind, at worst, to the document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popup-overlay .cross', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.popup-overlay').remove();
});
```

Ideally you'd pick a *static* (exists when the page loads/code executes and is never removed during the lifetime of the document) element that's as close as possible in the DOM to the dynamically added elements (your `.popup-overlay` ones) though.